# How to set the default binding converter in Wpf?

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm moving project from Silverlight to WPF and I've come across a problem.

I have a control with an INotifyPropertyChanged property GeoRect of type GeoRect. GeoRect has a variety of public properties that are set in its constructor each of type IGeoPosition.

I am setting a binding to one of these properties like so:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding GeoRect.TopRight, ElementName=x_SomeControl}"></TextBlock>
```

In Silverlight the default ToString method is called on IGeoPosition instance every time the GeoRect property changes. In Wpf I don't get any text at all.

I can correct this in Wpf by adding a ValueConverter to the TextBlock which simply calls the ToString method on the object, but this appears to be unnecessary fat. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that there is another problem in your binding. Also in WPF, data binding calls the ToString() method to build the text of a Text-control.
Have you checked the output window of visual studio for a binding error? Or maybe the GeoRect-class does not support INotifyPropertyChanged for the TopRight property?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought that WPF should behave like that. The backing field for the TopRight property is only ever set in the constructor. If I change the property to be return a string (and return the ToString method on the backing field object) then the correct result is achieved. It appears to be something in the way the interface is being dealt with. Mysterious!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `ElementName=x_SomeControl` and `GeoRect.TopRight` are causing a probable "Source and Path" comination error. Are you sure your `x_SomeControl` has a property called 'GeoRect'? Also is `x_SomeControl.GeoRect` not null? And `x_SomeControl.GeoRect.TopRight` has a correct value?

As HCL pointed out, this will become apparent when you view your Output window where BindingExpression error must have appeared for this binding.

Please check.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The output windows was my first of call, but no luck. I am sure that GeoRect isn't null, because if I add a value converter to the binding I can 'snoop' in and see that it isn't. Indeed calling ToString in a ValueConverter will work.